# Pushkin’s Eugene Onegin, the “lost” chapter 10

Tags: russian-language, translation, alexander-pushkin, eugene-onegin

Is there an English translation of the surviving stanzas of chapter 10 of Pushkin’s *Eugene Onegin*?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Onegin#Composition_and_publication):

> Pushkin wrote at least 18 stanzas of a never-completed tenth chapter.
>   It contained many satires and even direct criticism on contemporary
>   Russian rulers, including the Emperor himself. Afraid of being
>   prosecuted for dissidence, Pushkin burnt most of the tenth chapter.
>   Very little of it survived in Pushkin's notebooks.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to give more information to those readers (like myself) who might be unfamiliar with the issue about Ch. 10. If you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back (i.e. reject it).

Comment: By all means edit it to fill in the background. I’m not sure that I am seeing the edited version. I see that helpful tags have been added. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Princeton University Press website](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/4739.html) says that Nabokov included the remaining fragments of chapter 10 in his commentary on his translation of *Eugene Onegin*. This commentary was part of the first edition of Nabokov's translation (four volumes long), and is volume 2 of the current *Princeton University Press* edition.

Comment: Thank you Peter Schor! I will see if the book is available via interlibrary loan, If not, I may just go ahead and buy it.  From the description, I think this book is going to suit my needs perfectly! Большое спасибо!