# Pushkin’s Eugene Onegin, the “lost” chapter 10 in German

Tags: russian-language, translation, alexander-pushkin, eugene-onegin

### Is there a German translation of chapter 10 of Pushkin’s Eugene Onegin? The English one is available in ISBN 9780691019048."

Pushkin destroyed chapter X of Eugene Onegin, leaving only the encrypted quatrains. Apparently, for memory's sake. This chapter is considered to be irretrievably lost, and no evidence has yet been found that it exists in any list. In the 50's came the publication of X chapter, allegedly discovered by the historian D. Alshits, a fairly plausible explanation of the circumstances of the death allegedly found it original. Not a single serious literary scholar believed in the authenticity of the text. Even a formal analysis of the lexical material, rhyme and rhythm clearly showed that its parameters differ sharply from Pushkin's. Not to mention the artistic level of the lines belonging to the forger.

Comment: In English it was translated by Vladimir Nabokov: [Pushkin’s Eugene Onegin, the “lost” chapter 10](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/pushkin-s-eugene-onegin-the-lost-chapter-10).